# Mathematica Plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, linear-algebra

How can I plot List in Mathematica

Comment: Try to check documentation on ListPlot

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided the data, so here I am generating a list of the data,

```
listdata = Table[{t, t^(t/10)}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

Now plotting it using `ListPlot`,

```
ListPlot[listdata, PlotStyle -> Red]
```